# PHP DateTime как получить строку

Tags: php

Как получить строку, содержащую в себе дату вот в таком формате:

```
2016-03-20
```

Comment: А чем плох стандартный метод `<?= date("Y-m-d");?>` ?

Comment: А он вернет в таком формате строку? =)

Comment: Если да, то всем хорош

Comment: Именно так он и сделает =)

Comment: Благодарю. Прекрасно работает =)

Comment: @ОлегДёгтев, напишите, пожалуйста, ответ к вопросу.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?= date("Y-m-d");?>
```

Строка в формате YYYY-mm-dd

Answer (score 0):

В вашем вопросе дата не является текущей, на всякий случай дам пример как преобразовать в другой формат:

```
$date = date('d F Y', strtotime('2016-03-20'));
var_dump(is_string($date)); // bool(true)
echo $date; // 20 March 2016
```